# Limit in simple differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Given the differential equation: $$\frac{dv}{dt}=-g-kv$$

How can one deduce directly from this equation (**without solving** the differential equation first) that: $$\lim_{t\to \infty}v(t)=-\frac{g}{k}$$

Comment: If the motion ever stabilizes, the derivative vanishes.

Comment: You can also use the Laplace transform and the final value theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $v(t)$ 'stops changing' at infinity, what is $\frac{dv}{dt}$ at infinity?

---

To restate my comments below a bit: We can rewrite this ODE as $\frac{dv}{dt}=-k(v+g/k)$. If $v>-g/k$ at some time, then $dv/dt<0$ at that same moment and so $v$ will decrease. But $v$ can never cross $-g/k$, since then $dv/dt=0$ and it would have to be constant for all times before and after. So instead it must approach $-g/k$ from above, reaching it only asymptotically. (The logic is reversed if $v<-g/k$ instead.)

Comment: Ok, then $\frac{dv}{dt}=0$ and the rest follows. But why would $v(t)$ stop changing? What does that even mean?

Comment: What does the assumption about a limit existing imply? If the derivative doesn't go to zero then the function never stops 'moving' and the limit would not exist.

Comment: @ImreVégh: Your point could be phrased in another way: $v(t)=-g/k$ is the only steady-state solution, but why should we expect a generic solution to converge to it? The easiest way, I suspect, is to make the substitution $u(t)=v(t)+g/k$ and get the ODE $du/dt = -k u.$ Then all you have to convince yourself is that, regardless of the initial value of $u$, it will eventually decay to $u=0$.

Comment: @ImreVégh physically $v(t)$ becoming constant corresponds to a terminal velocity being reached (assuming this ODE is governing a particle falling under the influence of gravity). And a steady state is able to be reached in this equation as there is a "damping" term.

Comment: @David Well, I'm presupposing that such a limit actually exists; if it does, then $-g/k$ is the only possible value. That the limit does in fact exist can be shown in a few ways e.g. by a change of variables to get the exponential-decay ODE (see my previous comment to Imre) or by a physical argument as per okrzysik's comment.

Comment: @Semiclassical I agree, I was just trying to help give some intuition for Imre.

Answer (score 1):

This a linear equation, for which the solution is known to be the sum of the general solution of the homogeneous equation and a particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation.

If the system is stable, the transient components, i.e. the contribution of the homogeneous terms, will vanish over time.

So we can try to find a particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation

$$\frac{dv}{dt}+kv=-g.$$

As the RHS is a constant, a constant solution will do and

$$v=V$$ where $V$ matches $$0+kV=-g.$$